# Not key value coding-compliant for key?

Tags: ios, objective-c

In my my model base class, I have a method defined like so:

```
- (NSDictionary *)propertyDictionary
{
    NSMutableDictionary *props = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    unsigned int outCount, i;
    objc_property_t *properties = class_copyPropertyList([self class], &outCount);
    for (i = 0; i < outCount; i++) {
        objc_property_t property = properties[i];
        NSString *propertyName = [NSString stringWithCString:property_getName(property) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        id propertyValue = [self valueForKey:(NSString *)propertyName];
        if (propertyValue) [props setObject:propertyValue forKey:propertyName];
    }
    free(properties);
    return props;
}
```

Now, up until a day or two, this worked great. However, now with certain objects, I am all the sudden getting exceptions like

```
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key title.
```

Weird thing is, my class no longer has a declared property, 'title' -- I've deleted that property from object. What gives? Why would Ibe getting back an incorrect list of properties from `class_copyPropertyList`? HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah found it!

I declared the object as conforming to `<MKAnnotation>` in a category. Since the object no longer has its own accessors for `title` and `subtitle`, but MKAnnotation requires them, I get the crash